# I would like to know the explanation of why the reduce method is giving me a specific answer

Tags: javascript, arrays, logic, reduce

I have a basic code just to test and learn but I am expecting the result to be 81, but the console is always showing 91. So my guess that the method is not subtracting from the first value of the array. I want to make sure please if I am right and what can I do to make it subtract the 10 from all the values in the initial arrays.

```
const ages = [32, 33, 16, 40];

const total = ages.reduce((prev, curr) => {
  return prev + curr - 10;
});
```

I was expecting to get 81 as a result.

Comment: The current answer is `91` since `(((32+33-10)+16-10)+40-10)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When only the callback function is passed to [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), the first element of the array is taken as the initial value of the accumulator. Explicitly pass `0` as the second argument (initial value) instead.

```js
const ages = [32, 33, 16, 40];
const total = ages.reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr - 10, 0);
console.log(total);
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you provided, the result of the total variable should be 91 and not 81.

The reason for this is that the reduce() method is subtracting 10 from each element in the array and then adding up the resulting values. Here's how the calculation is being done:

The first element in the array is 32, so prev starts at 0 and curr is 32. The result of the calculation is 22 (32 - 10), which is added to prev.

The second element in the array is 33, so prev is now 22 and curr is 33. The result of the calculation is 45 (33 - 10 + 22), which is added to prev.

The third element in the array is 16, so prev is now 45 and curr is 16. The result of the calculation is 51 (16 - 10 + 45), which is added to prev.

The fourth element in the array is 40, so prev is now 51 and curr is 40. The result of the calculation is 81 (40 - 10 + 51), which is added to prev.

Please explain in a bit more detail what your expected result should be?What you want to accomplish?

Comment: Exactly! And this why I was expecting 81. You literally did the math that I was doing and resulted with the same number. But the console shows 91. So the math is wrong because the first number of the array is taken as the initial. The reduce doesn't subtract 10 out of it.